# Converting String to unique integer in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame of this type

```
string1,string2,value1
string3,string1,value2
string3,string5,value3
...
...
```

I would convert srings in unique integers:

```
1,2,value1
3,1,value2
3,5,value3
...
...
```

I am trying with c() operator, that convert the string in a unique integer. The problem is how to manage the two columns of the data frame. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you just trying to strip the letters and just have numbers remaining, or are you actually thinking of, say, a `?factor`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to assign numbers to the strings, rather than removing the text 'string', you can use a factor with known levels, then coerce to numeric.

```
d <- read.csv(header=TRUE, file=textConnection("a,b,c
string1,string2,value1
string3,string1,value2
string3,string5,value3"))

l=unique(c(as.character(d$a), as.character(d$b)))

d1 <- data.frame(a=as.numeric(factor(d$a, levels=l)), b=as.numeric(factor(d$b, levels=l)), c=d$c)
> d1
  a b      c
1 1 3 value1
2 2 1 value2
3 2 4 value3
```

Note that the numeric values chosen do not agree with the numerals in the strings, but each string is given a unique number.

Comment: If the desired factors are already known, something like `d[c("a", "b")] <- lapply(d[-3], factor, levels=paste("string", 1:5, sep=""))` might be useful for converting to factor.

Comment: @Matthew How can i keep track of the relation between string and integer in order to reverse the operation at some point?

Comment: You should remove the `as.numeric()` so you end up with factors.

Comment: You can also look them up in the vector used for factor levels. `l[1]` returns `string1`.

Comment: I would also recommend you just do in-place replacement: `df$a <- factor(...)` and `df$b <- factor(...)` rather than reassigning the whole data.frame (your solution is also specific about only a third column).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple solution using `match`:

```
df <- read.csv(text="string1,string2,value1
string3,string1,value2
string3,string5,value3", header = FALSE)

cbind(sapply(df[-3], match, unique(unlist(df[-3]))), df[3])

  V1 V2     V3
1  1  3 value1
2  2  1 value2
3  2  4 value3
```

*How it works*: The values of both columns are matched with a vector of unique numbers of these columns. This returns their positions.